# TortoiseSVN and Local Web Proxies

Tags: windows, svn, proxy, tortoisesvn

I have successfully configured TortoiseSVN to access a local Apache-served Subversion repository over https. My initial problem in configuring this scenario from my Windows client was discovered to be the proxy server I had established in the TortoiseSVN settings, which were unnecessary in our local environment.

However, for external repositories, the web proxy is necessary. As a result, I was hoping to find an option in TortoiseSVN equivalent to "Bypass proxy for local intranet sites" or a means to establish a proxy bypass list, but I've found neither, and I've not found a workaround in the research I've done so far. Came across a few posts here on SO that sounded promising, but amounted to manually disabling/enabling the web proxy as needed.

Am I missing something obvious, or will I simply need to enable/disable the proxy from TortoiseSVN depending on where the archive is located? This isn't insurmountable, of course, just a bit of a nuisance.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try downloading frozen Way, this worked for me, you just need to start it when you want to commit/upload and it's free .